# Segmentation fault when changing `std::string` in by pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers, c++11

I have a `std::string*` as a member of my class, however when I try to set its value to anything in the class constructor, I'm getting `segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Relevant code part:

```
// class declaration:
//...
std::string* _sensorString;
//...


// on class constructor
//...
std::cout << "test "<< std::endl;
*_sensorString="s";
std::cout << *_sensorString<< std::endl;
//...
```

Output of the program:

```
test 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Is _sensorString pointing to anything before you assign "s" to it?

Comment: Fire up gdb as follows:  gdb <filename> core.(whatever the core number) and type into the command: where, it should guide you as to where the segfault is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not allocate memory for the object,

```
std::string* _sensorString;
```

You should write

```
_sensorString = new std::string;
```

before writing

```
*_sensorString="s";
```

Comment: There's hardly a reason for doing this. You normally use std::string because you don't want to use a pointer at all.

Comment: @PMF i do not understand why you wrote this comment to my answer. You could do this in your own answer. Also you could ask the author of the thread what is the reason of using the pointer. Maybe he simply learn C++.

Comment: I could have asked, I agree. But from the context I think the OP is really a beginner on stl, so your answer (although clearly it is correct) is pointing to the wrong direction IMO.

Comment: @PMF Please next time do not comment my answers. If you know the right direction then simply describe it in your own answer.

Comment: It is completely reasonable to comment on an existing answer, especially when the comment is as useful and correct as @PMF's is.

Answer (score 6):

Yea, obviously. `std::string*` is a pointer, and assigning a value to a pointer when the pointer has not been initialized causes a segmentation fault. The standard template library helps you with *objects* so that you do not need pointers. Just declare your type as

```
 std::string _sensorString;
```

then you can use it as

```
 _sensorString = "s";
```

Comment: I am using it as a way to share the string between separate threads. Obviously both ways work, I was just experimenting.